# Sed to replace certain number of occurrences

Tags: sed

I have the replace sed script below and it works for the first occurrence of every line but I'm trying to make it work for the first 2 occurrences per line instead of one (/1) or the whole line (/g):

```
sed -r '2,$s/(^ *|, *)([a-z])/\1\U\2/1'
```

Is there any way to do that either by combining sed commands or creating a script?

Comment: twice the `s///`action with `/1` (`1` is optionnal in this case), there is not X times. Other solution is to build the regex including the 2 occurences

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best I can offer is

```
sed -r '2,$ { s/(^|,) *[a-z]/\U&/; s//\U&/; }'
```

The `\U&` trick uses the fact that the upper case version of a space is still a space; this is to make the repetition shorter. Because captures are no longer used, the regex can be simplified a little.

In the second `s` command, the `//` is a stand-in for the most recently attempted regex, so the first one is essentially executed a second time (this time matching what was originally the second appearance).

Since `/1` doesn't actually do anything (replacing the first occurrence is default), I took the liberty of removing it.

Comment: wow awesome! this works like a charm! The reason the /1 was there was because I used the same to turn first letter of the second column into uppercase, so basically I was using either /1 or /2 just to seem more clear to me.